# Fastest way to copy files locally in linux

Tags: linux, shell

So for performance reasons I decided to move 2TB of small files, randomly written during some time - from a 14TB SATA HDD to a 4TB m.2 NVME SSD, both locally attached.

I've been struggling for 2 days straight to get reasonable copy performance.

`cp` gets ~15MB/s, wich gives me an estimate of about two days of nonstop copying

`rsync` is even worse at ~5MB/s

I guess the poor performance is due to a randomness of physical location on the platter which brings me to a 'random read' performance marks.

Still, I'm pretty sure these 2TB of files are a semi-contiguous region of the 14TB drive, so simply `dd`'ing that region even with a 20% 'miss' overhead would give me a close to 200MB/s rated sequential read. I'll just 'throw away' the files I didn't need - but I can't find any software/method that would do it that way.

My question is, what is the fastest way to copy files locally in 2021?

Answer (score 1):

No its not due to fragmentation, small files on mechanical disk gets copied very slow. It is better to wait. No magic bullet this time.

Comment: From what I can tell, there are several solutions that are much faster than `cp` and `rsync`: [gcp](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/gcp.1.html), [parcp](https://blogs.oracle.com/cloud-infrastructure/announcing-parallel-file-tools-for-file-storage), [parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/), [fpsync](https://github.com/martymac/fpart), [Mutil](https://github.com/pkolano/mutil) and copying files is a [known problem in linux](https://lwn.net/Articles/789623/)